# Tridion core service giving 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: 2011, core-service

Tridion core service i.e "https://xxxxxx.xxx/webservices/CoreService2011.svc) gives following error when I hit it in browser

> "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied".

My tridion url uses SSO authentication and I am able to access the SDL Tridion portal and I have admin access.

Here is my web.config file.

```xml
<configuration>
  <tridionConfigSections>
    <sections>
      <clear />
      <add filePath="..\config\Tridion.ContentManager.config" />
    </sections>
  </tridionConfigSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <httpModules>
    </httpModules>
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="svc-Integrated" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Temp\CoreService\IISHost.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" maxMessagesToLog="1000" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CoreService_basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="StreamDownload_basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedResponse" messageEncoding="Mtom" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="StreamUpload_basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="209715200" transferMode="StreamedRequest" messageEncoding="Mtom" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreServiceBehavior" name="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreService2010">
        <endpoint address="basicHttp_2010" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CoreService_basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttp_2010" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.ICoreService2010" />
        <endpoint address="streamDownload_basicHttp_2010" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamDownload_basicHttpBinding" name="streamDownload_basicHttp_2010" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.IStreamDownload2010" />
        <endpoint address="streamUpload_basicHttp_2010" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamUpload_basicHttpBinding" name="streamUpload_basicHttp_2010" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.IStreamUpload2010" />
        <endpoint address="wsHttp_2010" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttp_2010" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.ISessionAwareCoreService2010">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreServiceBehavior" name="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreService2011">
        <endpoint address="basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CoreService_basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttp" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.ICoreService2011" />
        <endpoint address="streamDownload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamDownload_basicHttpBinding" name="streamDownload_basicHttp" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.IStreamDownload2011" />
        <endpoint address="streamUpload_basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamUpload_basicHttpBinding" name="streamUpload_basicHttp" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.IStreamUpload2011" />
        <endpoint address="wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" name="wsHttp" bindingNamespace="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.ISessionAwareCoreService2011">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Tridion.ContentManager.ServiceHost.IISHost.CoreServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization>
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="Tridion.Security.IdentityModel.ClaimsPrincipalAuthorizationPolicy, Tridion.Security, Version=3.0.0.211, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to use the *webservices* endpoint (which is hosted in IIS), you would need to implement the authentication mechanism required by your SSO solution.

Unless this is a requirement, I'd suggest that you instead switch to using the *netTcp* binding which is hosted by the Tridion Core Service Host service. That one is set up to use Windows authentication by default.

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem because I was using SSL certificate as my user authentication and it was not able to check the revocation. I figured this out using the under given link. There is a simple registry tweak which saved my lot of time. I hope someone will get some help from this.
http://www.windowstechupdates.com/403-forbidden-access-is-denied-you-do-not-have-permission-to-view-this-directory-or-page-using-the-credentials-that-you-supplied/